# What are the advantages of using Subversion?

Tags: svn, repository, project, collaboration

What are the advantages of using Subversion over email for two persons collaborating on writing a document?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean using Subversion *instead of* email?

Comment: Yes, I mean using Subversion instead of email.

Comment: If youre just writing a document, id say use google docs :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Subversion, or pretty much any version control system, is certainly better than email.  It maintains a history of all the changes.  This way you do not end up with a zillion copies of your document that you cannot make heads or tails out of.  With a version control system, every time you commit a set of changes you write a comment describing what you did.  Then you can look over the log to see what was changed when and by whom.  You can easily look at the differences between versions and easily roll back changes if you need to.  You also always have easy remote access to the current version of your document without having to remember which file name you used for it: you simply do an update of your working directory, or checkout the head version.